# regex - split only if a letter followed by comma + comma + ignore comma in bracket

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to figure out a way to split values based on a comma in regex but the problem is that I want to ignore commas that are inside the parenthesis ()

example :

```
'hist1234,geog293,lap_933,(a-20,110,60),(z-8,9,10),POLY5,9,3,8,ro water'
```

expected output :

```
['hist1234', 'geog293', 'lap_933', '(a-20,110,60)', '(z-8,9,10)', 'POLY5,9,3,8', 'ro water']
```

I tried: ,\s*(?![^()]*)) for the comma and ignoring the comma in brackets but im unsure about the ignoring if its a number followed by a comma

Comment: Do you know this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags IMHO your case is similar.

Comment: I need to use Regex not to parse through HTML but for another application

Comment: The regex code also works, I just need help with the number followed by comma part

Comment: There's hardly a difference between round braces and angle brackets... Is it guaranteed that there's no parenthesis inside a parenthesis?

Comment: no parenthesis inside a parenthesis in this one yep

Answer (score 2):

Since you guaranteed "no parenthesis inside a parenthesis" then this would work:

**regex**

```regex
,(?![^()]+\))(?=[a-zA-Z(])
```

**replace**

```
,
```

^ comma + space

If splitting then just ignore the **replace**.

https://regex101.com/r/Mk8mAI/1

- `,` - capture a comma
- `(?![^()]+\))` - guarantee that ahead of me is not content followed by a closing parenthesis
- `(?=[a-zA-Z(])` - guarantee that ahead of me is a letter or opening parenthesis